# Scaling down Image for ImageButton programmatically

Tags: android

I have many icons in 512 x 512 resolution and i want to set them
on ImageButtons. Ofcourse i dont want the ImageButtons to be 
512 x 512 big i want them to be as big as its optimal for the
screen size of the current device.

I create my buttons like this:

```
this.buttonMeasure = new ImageButton(this);
this.buttonMeasure.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_measure);
this.buttonMeasure.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

How can i scale down the images to an optimal size dependent 
to the screen size of the device programmatically?

I tried this but that leads to an outOfMemoryError:

```
public static Bitmap getScaledBitMap(Context context, Drawable sourceDrawable) {
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)sourceDrawable).getBitmap();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int width = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity;
    float scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be needing this at all. You specify the size of your `ImageButton` using properties like `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for different layouts in folders, Similarly you need to place copy of  images of various resolutions in respective folders with the same name.The appropriate image is automatically picked up by android itself at run time.
[image]

Comment: I did that before. I placed 24x24 icons in ldpi, 48x48 in mdbi, ...
unfortunately they arent used automatically. it always uses the ones i added first (dont know why) and even if the icons where created in high quality the smaller the icon gets the more pixeled it is (very low quality). Also i dont use xml file. I create them programmatically